# I added some options to stop spam with Postfix, but now won't send email to remote domains

Tags: centos, postfix, centos6

I had a working Postfix server, but added a few lines to my main.cf in a hope to block some common spam.

Those lines I added were:

```
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,
        reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,
        reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
        reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
        reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net,
        reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com,
        permit
```

It appears my postfix is now receiving normal emails fine, and blocking spam emails. But when I now try to use this server myself to send to a remote domain (an email not on my server) I get bounced, with maillog saying something like this:

```
Nov 12 06:19:36 srv postfix/smtpd[11756]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 
unknown[xx.xx.x.xxx]: 450 4.1.2 <somegmailaddress@gmail.com>: Recipient address 
rejected: Domain not found; from=<hello@primarydomain.net> 
to=<somegmailaddress@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.100]>
```

Is that saying 'domain not found' for gmail.com? Why is that recipient address rejected?

An output of my postconf-n is:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = primarydomain.net
myhostname = mail.primarydomain.net
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination, primarydomain.net, secondarydomain.org
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,            reject_unknown_recipient_domain,            reject_unauth_pipelining,            permit_mynetworks,            permit_sasl_authenticated,            reject_unauth_destination,            reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,            reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,            reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,            reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,            reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,            reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,            reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,            reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,            reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,            reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net,            reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com,            permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
soft_bounce = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = mail.secondarydomain.org
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Edit: here is the dig mx gmail.com from the server:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> mx gmail.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31766
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 14

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.      1207    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1207    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1207    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1207    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1207    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmail.com.      109168  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
gmail.com.      109168  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
gmail.com.      109168  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
gmail.com.      109168  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 207 IN A   173.194.70.27
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 248 IN AAAA    2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 200 IN  A   173.194.67.26
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 248 IN  AAAA    2a00:1450:400c:c05::1b
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 207 IN A   74.125.143.27
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 249 IN AAAA    2a00:1450:400c:c05::1b
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 207 IN A   173.194.69.27
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 248 IN AAAA    2a00:1450:4008:c01::1b
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 207 IN A   173.194.79.27
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 249 IN AAAA    2607:f8b0:400e:c01::1a
ns2.google.com.     281970  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     281970  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     281970  IN  A   216.239.38.10
ns1.google.com.     281970  IN  A   216.239.32.10
```

Comment: You forgot to post a copy of your `/etc/resolv.conf` and also _test_ DNS resolution.

Comment: Pasting the output of `dig mx gmail.com` (on the server) into your question would be particularly helpful.

Comment: Do not **ever** use `reject_rbl_client`. And even more do not use it multiple times. You will be rejecting good mails and not even noticing properly. Use some weighted tool like [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org/) or [bley](http://bley.mx).

Comment: @MadHatter I added the dig mx of gmail.com into the question. It seems like it is ok, isn't it?

Comment: @zhenech ok - I thought these would just block spam emails that have been added to these spam databases - are you saying good domains get added to these lists?

Comment: @zhenech I would not say "don't **ever**". Some of them are perfectly safe to reject, like spamhaus. Others really need to be put through a weighting system. And some of them...nobody should use at all.

Comment: @michaelhampton It just has my nameserver Ip's 'nameserver 77.235.33.38
nameserver 77.235.33.116'

Comment: The problem with RBLs is the fact that everyone makes mistakes and IP addresses change quickly.
Even spamhaus can list a "good" IP address. And with reject_rbl_client you are trusting the RBL completely.

Sometimes, some accounts get hacked and used for spam, voila, the ip address of the server gets listed in a RBL and noone can send mails from that server anymore.
Or you are getting a new subnet from your provider, and previously, there was a spammer on that subnet. No mail for you (at least for some time).

Comment: There are some more arguments against RBLs here: http://www.whirlycott.com/phil/antispam/rbl-bad/rbl-bad.html
I (for myself) would not say RBLs are bad, just that they should not be used as the primary reject reason.

Thanks so much for the character limit... Narf.

Comment: @zhenech Thanks for explaining all that. But this wouldn't be the reason why I can't send an outgoing mail would it?

Comment: @willdanceforfun: nope, that's just a flaw I saw in your config and thought it would be good to be fixed for the future :)

Comment: @zhenech thanks for the tip though. Makes sense what you said. I'm going to try running with just spamhaus for a while because I am a super newb, configuring more difficult things is harder, and i'm getting rained on with spam.

Answer (score 2):

You should really put these two lines first in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions =`

> permit_mynetworks,
>   permit_sasl_authenticated,

As those should be automatic (make sure to set mynetworks as well) marks of validity for your senders. The `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` option has three options, Yes, No, or Dunno. Yes or No mean stop processing, Dunno means go to the next option. You want to short circuit authenticated senders, and people in the local trusted network. You could even put `permit_sasl_authenticated` first.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Nick. I've changed the order of the rules now.

Comment: Did it change anything with the rejected behaviour?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this was the issue, but perhaps a network issue. I removed "reject_unknown_recipient_domain" which then revealed the following in my logs when sending to my test gmail account " connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c05::1b]:25: Network is unreachable" - it then appears to keep trying, and then relays a few seconds later. That looks like an ipv6 there, but then the relay that works appears to be via regular old ip. To be honest, I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Do you have IPv6 connectivity? If not, set `inet_protocols = ipv4` in your main.cf